# Handling requests of format */* for rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, jbuilder

When I curl or another server calls my server it interprets the format as `*/*`. Since I've installed jbuilder it always repsonds with json.

How can I adjust the preference order for formats to respond to `*/*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem had to do with the `respond_to` action.

With an action that has:

```
respond_to do |fmt|
  fmt.json
  fmt.html
end
```

Any request of type `*/*` will be json.

To make it html you just need to make it the first format that's responded to:

```
respond_to do |fmt|
  fmt.html
  fmt.json
end
```